# Return to previous page when user clicks 'back' button Android InAppWebView Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, webview, android-webview, flutter-inappwebview

I'm using the InAppWebView (https://inappwebview.dev/) package in my Flutter app.

When the user clicks on the back button, it's closing the app.

I wanna make it go to the previous page of the webview.

The closest I got was this link...
https://inappwebview.dev/blog/inappwebview-the-real-power-of-webviews-in-flutter/#inappwebview-simple-example

... where it shows the `_webViewController.goBack()` method.

The point now seems to be knowing how to intercept the Android 'back' button and call such method above.

Thank you!

P.S.: in iOS it works fine with the swipe gesture for navigating back.

Comment: is it mandatory to use `inappwebview` plugin?? if not you may try another plugin like https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter  or https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the scaffold with a `WillPopScope` class and check if there is any webview history when the user press back. If there is history use `_webViewController.goBack()` else pop the scope.

```
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if(await _webViewController.canGoBack()){
            _webViewController.goBack();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(),
)
```

Comment: Right, thank you! Just needed to add async/await on it and it worked